# Azure DevOps Project Now Showing up in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, virtual-machine, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to access my Azure DevOps repo using Visual Studio 2019 from a VM. But projects were not getting listed even after login. Previously the Projects used to visible. But now it is not showing up. But I could access the repo from the Visual Studio 2019 installed in my laptop.[image]

Comment: Did you click on `dev.azure.com` ? Also try a refresh

Comment: Yeah. I tried. But no luck. It should show my Organization Name and repos under it.

Comment: Projects are separate from the repos. I am not sure projects are visible on the Team Explorer.

Comment: Yeah.. ultimately repository should show up.. But nothing is loading there.

Answer (score 0):

I myself fixed this issue with this reference (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-tls12). All you need to do is run the script AzureDevOpsTls12Analysis.ps1 available at this location and follow the steps as shown during script execution.